# Creating a "Section" page with XAML on Windows 8

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am working on my first Windows 8 Metro app. I have worked a LOT with Silverlight and I am familiar with the Metro concepts. My challenge is, I know I want to create a "Section" page as defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761500.aspx.  Or, to put it another way, like the sample "Finance" app where "TODAY", "INDICES", "NEWS", etc. represent sections. But, I can't figure out how a "Section" page is defined in XAML.

I was expecting it to be similar to a tab control where each section is defined as a child of the parent control in the "Items" collection. However, I can't seem to find a solid example. Does anyone know an example they can point me to? Or a walkthrough online?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to create groups in a GridView?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a frame in your "master" page, and then adding other pages to that frame. A section in this paradigm is just a normal page. Most of the samples [here in MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples) uses this type of design, with a master page displaying different sections, based on a selected item in a listview.